# React Router v4 <Link> for Form

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4

How can I use `<Link>` with a `<form>`? I am trying to avoid programatic routing as I see many warnings against it.

Form has two fields:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="what"/>
    <input type="text" id="where"/>
    <Link><button type="submit"></Link>
</form>
```

My goal is to send the page to `'/' + document.getElementById('where').value + '/' + document.getElementById('what').value`, is it possible with v4 router?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With v4, the `<Link>` is only used to create `<a>` elements.

I think that most warnings against programmatic navigation come from people not really understanding how `history` works, especially when attempting to do it outside of components. The `withRouter` HOC provides an easy way to add routing to a component.

Additionally, I would do the routing from within a form component instead of from the button. Then, you just need to make sure that the button's type is `submit` (which is the default).

You are also using DOM functions to access the values in your code. I would recommend instead using controlled inputs, but that is obviously up to you.

```js
class NavForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      what: '',
      where: ''
    }

    this.submitHandler = this.submitHandler.bind(this)
    this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this)
  }

  handleInput(event) {
    const target = event.target
    this.setState({
      [target.name]: target.value
    })
  }  

  submitHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    // do some sort of verification here if you need to
    this.props.push(`${this.state.where}/${this.state.what}`)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
        <input
          type='text'
          name='what'
          value={this.state.what}
          onChange={this.handleInput} />
        <input
          type='text'
          name='where'
          value={this.state.where}
          onChange={this.handleInput} />
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(NavForm)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @PaulS for such a detailed answer, and so fast! :)