# How to submit form with React Link component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using BrowserRouter in my React project, but there is a form page where I want to use a Link component to: submit the form and to redirect me to the homepage without reloading the page.

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

   /* blablabla */

   <Link to={`/homepage`} className="button">
       Home
   </Link>

</form>
```

But since the Link is an "a" component I can't make it "type=submit". So my problem is not about how to redirect to homepage, because it works, my problem is that I want to also submit the form.

How can I use the Link React component to redirect to the homepage without reloading the page AND ALSO to submit the form.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Router v4 <Link> for Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42060961/react-router-v4-link-for-form)

Comment: I'm not really working with class

Comment: That's irrelevant here.  The same solution applies.

Comment: @jmargolisvt as I interpret it, I would need to have the props in which I push the "/homepage". But where do I get the props here and how do I apply it in the Link?

Comment: you can programmatically navigate using react router after the form is submitted.

Comment: There's a react-router `Form` element as well  https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with **useHistory** in your submit function

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";


export default function App() {
  let history = useHistory();

  const handleSubmit = e => {
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
   ...                                
   history.push("/homepage");
  };

  return (
   <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
     ...
     <button type="submit">Create</button>
   </form>
  )
};
```

Demo : [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-3tz9ja?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyForm%2FMyForm.js)

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I was looking for! However the whole goal of mine was that I wanted to validate some form fields before letting the user to submit it. This method overrides the "required" thing on the input field, somehow it won't stop the submitting. Anyways, an "if" case solved this problem. Thanks again!

Comment: @Pettko yes, you need to use a condition to verify if the input field is empty or not before the redirection. You can check 2 demos here with validation and redirection (first one with react-boostrap, the second with Material-ui and react-hook-form) -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66676556/how-to-copy-input-data-from-one-component-to-another-component/66678662?noredirect=1#comment117993536_66678662

Answer (score 0):

In react-router-dom version 6

`useHistory()` is replaced by `useNavigate()`

```
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';

const navigate = useNavigate();
navigate('/home')
```